# Google Apps Email quota

Tags: gmail

I have a Google Apps account and one of the users has an Email Quota of 99% (with a red bar).

I've logged into the users' email account and deleted all the emails and then went to the trash, and then emptied the trash but the Email Quota is still 99%.

How do I reduce the email quota so that I can begin receiving emails again please?

Answer (score 1):

I've encountered this problem with users using their google apps email via having it setup as an imap account in Outlook.

Because Gmail is setup via imap and because Gmail only stored one actual copy of the email and adds tags to it so that it can be in multiple "folders" at a time, delete doesn't do what most people are used to it doing.  The mapping of the delete action in Outlook to the imap action is that gmail removes the tag of whatever folder the message was tagged with, but does not really delete the message.  It is still in the All Mail folder.  You will have to go into the all mail folder and move it to the imap trash can, and then empty that.

I've been working around it by using tag filters on a search in all mail for messages with no tags and then moving those to the trash can and emptying it.